# Using InvokeRequired when not a Form

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have an event handler, which I want to be handled in the original thread where the object was created, so that it doesn't block. With forms, it's easy to use InvokeRequired to force it to the original thread. But how do you do this if your class is not a Form?

Thanks,

PM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not going to be easy. First, you will have to create some kind message receiving loop on the thread in question. Then you will need to implement `ISynchronizeInvoke` in such a manner that it posts a message containing the delegate to execute into a queue that the target thread can pick up and extract that delegate and execute it. The producer-consumer pattern is often useful for setting this up. The important thing to take away is that you cannot just marshal any delegate onto any thread. The target thread has to be specially designed for this to work. It works in UI threads because `Application.Run` gets a message loop going that the `Control.Invoke` method uses.

Answer (score 2):

With the Forms/Controls, the invoked delegate gets placed in the UI message pump. Invoking onto the thread that an object was created on would be require some sort of message pump mechanism on that thread.

If it is created on the UI thread, you best bet would be to grab a reference to a UI control and invoke on the UI control. If its a thread created elsewhere, you will have to implement you own mechanism.

Answer (score -1):

Create your background threads with a special name and check `Thread.CurrentThread.Name` to see if it is a background or UI.

You can also use `Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground` if you are creating your threads in background so it is false for UI thread.

Comment: Yeah, but this is not meant to be a UI thread at all, otherwise I could just InvokeRequired...

Comment: You cannot call InvokeRequired on a thread. You call it on the form. Create the thread with a name and check the name, I told you.

Comment: How would you force the thread to change though? As far as I understand, with forms, the Invoke function basically forces it into the thread where the UI was created. How do you do this with regular threads? (i.e.: you check the name you see it's not the same, how do you get into the other thread and make this happen there)